# Prism How to add UserControl in UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

(My English is not very good. Please forgive me if there are any mistakes)

I defined a UserControl in the project

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MenuTreeRegion"/>
```

How can I add a UserControl to this

I tried to add in the ViewModel constructor

```
 _regionManager.RequestNavigate("MenuTreeRegion", "SettingMenuTree");
```

app.xaml add

```
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<SettingModuleView>();
```

But I can't add a UserControl to the contentcontrol in UserControl

Thank you first

Comment: What's the error you get from the navigation (in the callback)?

Comment: @Haukinger There are no prompts and errors .The interruption point sees that the method has passed

Comment: `RequestNavigation` accepts a callback that gets passed the exception if any occurs.

Comment: This is my fault,I wrote it in the constructor@Haukinger